# Implementing Enqueue and Dequeue for Queue using Alloy

Tags: queue, alloy

Having the following:

```
sig Queue { root: Node }
sig Node { next: lone Node }
fact nextNotReflexive { no n:Node | n = n.next }
fact nextNotCyclic { no n:Node | n in n.^next }
```

Can anyone help on the implementation of the Enq and Deq?

```
pred Enq[q,q':Queue, n:Node]{}
pred Deq [q,q':Queue]{}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

You can define enqueue easily:

```
pred Enq[q, q': Queue, n: Node] {
  q'.root = n and n.next = q.root
}
```

But dequeue is not nearly as easy. The problem is that you need to modify a Node, not a Queue, in order to make the change to the last node that's required to dequeue an element. You actually need to replace the second-to-last Node in the Queue with a different Node whose "next" field is empty -- but since you're using atom identity to represent node uniqueness, that Node will actually be a different Node.